# Wacom One Stylus not working

Tags: wacom, stylus

I am using Wacom One on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Budgie), but the stylus pen is not detectable.

```
xsetwacom --list devices
```

gives

```
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Wacom One Pen Display 13 stylus  id: 21  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Wacom One Pen Display 13 eraser  id: 22  type: ERASER    


libwacom-list-local-devices
```

results in

```
# Device node: /dev/input/event23
[Device]
Name=Wacom One Pen Display 13
ModelName=DTC133
DeviceMatch=usb:056a:03a6;
Class=PenDisplay
Width=11
Height=6
IntegratedIn=Display;
Styli=0xffffe;0xfffff;

[Features]
Reversible=false
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=false
TouchSwitch=false
# StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=0

---------------------------------------------------------------
# Device node: /dev/input/event22
[Device]
Name=Wacom One Pen Display 13
ModelName=DTC133
DeviceMatch=usb:056a:03a6;
Class=PenDisplay
Width=11
Height=6
IntegratedIn=Display;
Styli=0xffffe;0xfffff;

[Features]
Reversible=false
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=false
TouchSwitch=false
# StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=0

---------------------------------------------------------------
# Device node: /dev/input/event21
[Device]
Name=Wacom One Pen Display 13
ModelName=DTC133
DeviceMatch=usb:056a:03a6;
Class=PenDisplay
Width=11
Height=6
IntegratedIn=Display;
Styli=0xffffe;0xfffff;

[Features]
Reversible=false
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=false
TouchSwitch=false
# StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=0

---------------------------------------------------------------
```

I urgently need the pen (which was working some months before I updated Ubuntu) for my university lessons and would be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot and best wishes.

Comment: xinput enable XXX where XXX is the id number from xinput (if it shows). maybe enable touchscreen or touchpad to trigger pen. id numbers change on reboot a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, it did not help.

Comment: I have had it that I needed to enable the touchpad to get the pen to work, or touchscreen.

Comment: Hello. thanks to all of you who answered my question. Today, I found my solution: sudo xsetwacom set "Wacom One Pen Display 13 Pen stylus" mode absolute. I am very happy. Best wishes and happy weekend.